# Is any language a formal language?

Tags: logic

> Definition of formal language in wikipedia :  formal language is a set of strings of symbols that may be constrained by rules that are specific to it.

For example, let's take (meaningful) English words, **symbols**. Then, give the English grammar rule to form strings. So, English is a formal language.

What's wrong here? Or English a really formal language?

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint, the problem is the same as if you speak of "the set $A$ of all tasty apples." Membership in the set is not defined in a mathematically precise way. Likewise, while there may be some good approximations of a formal definition of what English is, these are not exactly accurate.

Comment: @user204305 Why should the membership be precise? Isn't any subset of the set of all finite strings of symbols a formal language?

Comment: For one thing, it can be logically problematic to consider a subset of a given set that is defined by a vague property. For example, let $n$ be the minimum of the set $A$ of all natural numbers that "cannot be defined in fewer than thirty English words." If $A$ were in fact a set, the existence of $n$ would clearly lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @user204305 Hmm... I'm asking whether a natural language is a formal language, not that it is a concsistent logical system. Since this is completely my guess, please don't get offended..:) I'm a beginner. Here is how I think. First, we define what formal language is, then put truth values and other stuffs to make it a formal logical system. Am I wrong?

Comment: Look, I may have misunderstood your question. I thought you were saying "How can something as imprecisely defined as English be a formal language?" But actually, it seems you're saying something like "Suppose we can write down a complete, finite description of what constitutes an English sentence. Then is English a formal language?" In this case, yes. But if you are saying that we should take English as it really is, then I would have to say that this isn't a mathematical question.

Comment: @user204305 yes this is not a mathematical question.. Indeed philosophical. I just realized that there is a philosophy.stackexchange.com.. Sorry for this and thank you:)

Comment: In your quotation you have omitted the start : "In mathematics, computer science, and linguistics ...". Chomsky's theory, called [Generative grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_grammar) was aimed at identifying a finite set of rules sufficient to produce all meaningful sentence of the human language; in this sense, it is linked to the mathematical study of formal languages.

Answer (score 2):

The definition on Wikipedia is now improved: "a formal language consists of words whose letters are taken from an alphabet and are well-formed according to a specific set of rules. "

No one has managed to identify a set of rules that draw a clear line between grammatical and ungrammatical English, even for a specific dialect. So English is not know to be a formal language, and almost certainly is not.

Note also that this definition is about syntax, not meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the proper conclusion is "English is not a formal language" or just "English is a formal language, but nobody has managed to identify *which* formal language it is".

Comment: At the end, was it `now` or as you pointed; `know`? I think it is `known`

Comment: The problem is not mainly that no one has supplied the grammar. The problem is more that no one has a robust definition of "English". I doubt whether my idiolect is a formal language, but even if it is, the set of sentences you make is different than the set of sentences I make.